# How to calculate predicted r2 in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, regression

I am trying to calculate predicted r2, I have code which I think should work, but the output for predicted r2 is 'none'. I'm not sure if this means it's 0 or if something is going wrong?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
y_true= Y
y_pred = xgboostmodel.predict(X)
xs = X

def press_statistic(y_true, y_pred, xs):
    res = y_pred - y_true
    hat = xs.dot(np.linalg.pinv(xs))
    den = (1 - np.diagonal(hat))
    sqr = np.square(res/den)
    return sqr.sum()

def predicted_r2(y_true, y_pred, xs):
    press = press_statistic(y_true=y_true,
                            y_pred=y_pred,
                            xs=xs
    )
    
def r2(y_true, y_pred):
    """
    Calculation of the unadjusted r-squared, goodness of fit metric
    """
    sse  = np.square( y_pred - y_true ).sum()
    sst  = np.square( y_true - y_true.mean() ).sum()
    return 1 - sse/sst

print(r2(y_true, y_pred))
print(predicted_r2(y_true, y_pred, xs))
```

Printing the r2 works and gives 0.87

Printing the predicted r2 just outputs `none` - what is going wrong here if anything?

Comment: You are missing the `return`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `return` after defining the `predicted_r2` function. I assume you need to return the `press` variable previously defined within the function:

```
def predicted_r2(y_true, y_pred, xs):
    press = press_statistic(y_true=y_true,
                            y_pred=y_pred,
                            xs=xs)
    return press
```

Comment: Thank you this has resolved it - will tick when I can

Comment: Glad to be of help! All functions will return `None` unless something different is specified!